# Stop Map to change it's direction whenever markers are updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Below is the code of my react-leaflet simple map, i have given center and zoom values

```
<Map
  center={[-30.036294, 20.71996]}
  zoom={5.8}>
  {markers.map(m => {
      return <Marker position={[m.latitude, m.longitude]} />
  })}
</Map>
```

whenever i try to update position of markers map move it's direction, i understand that `marker` is a state and when i update state `Map` should re-rendered but it won't even go to center position it just randomly change position. What i want do is i don't want map to change it's direction whenever i update markers. I am using `react-leaflet: v2.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, based on the documentation of leaflet and without knowing more about the code, that the marker gets focussed when moving it on the map. The api for a marker in leaflet has an option `autoPanOnFocus` which is set to true by default. This option does not seem to be present on the marker component. You could try manually adding the marker using the marker constructor and adding it to the map using the useMap hook. Another aproach could be to disable the panning alltogether when updating the marker position.

Sidenote: From experience I know that the center position for the map component is only a starting point for leaflet. Any changes after that do not keep the map at the center. Disabeling panning could fix that.

Comment: i did that but map is still moving. Can you give an example code?

Comment: Can you first provide the code you use to prevent the map from panning.